# KVC: How do I save UIKit structs in plist?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-graphics

I am using KVC to set properties of objects from a plist. I know I can save them as strings `<string>{{66, 114}, {64, 64}}</string>` and manually convert to structs, but how can I save for example a CGPoint or CGRect in a plist in a way that Cocoa KVC would understand? The [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html) seems to indicate that I need to save them as `NSValue`s. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Key-Value Coding Programming Guide seems to indicate that I need to save them as NSValues.

No, you need an NSValue to pass a point or rectangle to `setValue:forKey:`. The KVC docs aren't talking about saving the values anywhere, since that isn't part of KVC. And you can't save an NSValue in a property list, since it isn't one of the [property list](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/) classes.

So, you need to convert the rectangle to and from one of the property-list data types. I prefer to convert them to and from strings, which you can do with [some of the functions in UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW34).

These are actually Core Graphics structures, not UIKit (hence the names *CG*Point and *CG*Rect), so you might expect Core Graphics to have functions for this. Indeed it does, but of a different sort: In [CGGeometry](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/), Core Graphics provides functions to convert CGPoints and CGRects to and from dictionaries.

Strings or dictionaries: It's your choice. Whichever you choose, they are property lists, so you can store them in your property list output.

On retrieval, convert the dictionary or string to a point or rectangle, and [create an NSValue with that](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/) to pass to `setValue:forKey:`. Of course, this works in reverse the other way: When saving, `valueForKey:` will give you an NSValue, from which you need to extract the point or rectangle to convert to a dictionary or string to save in the plist.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It looks like strings are easier because I want to edit the plists.